# Plotting consecutive histograms with time slider in Plotly Python

Tags: python, histogram, plotly

I generate daily two histograms from data, one with the needed values and the other with the reached values for different stations. I want to plot these histograms side by side, like the bottom pink example [in Plotly here](https://plot.ly/python/histograms/#styled-histograms) (see link for source code). However, since both histograms are generated daily, I need to add a time slider to the graph, like the bottom example ['Simple Slider' from Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/sliders/) (see link for source code).

My problem is that the first example uses

```
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='Sine Wave Slider')
```

to plot the histogram, while for the slider the following is used:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='styled histogram')
```

My (not functioning) code right now is looking like this, where I try to plot the same 2 histograms 3 times. How can I change the code to generate a figure that uses both histograms (both with different random data) and the slider at the same time?

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x0 = np.random.randn(500)
x1 = np.random.randn(500)+1

trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=x0,
    histnorm='count',
    name='control',
    autobinx=False,
    xbins=dict(
        start=-3.5,
        end=3.0,
        size=0.5
    ),
    marker=dict(
        color='#FFD7E9',
    ),
    opacity=0.75
)
trace2 = go.Histogram(
    x=x1,
    name='experimental',
    autobinx=False,
    xbins=dict(
        start=-2.0,
        end=5,
        size=0.5
    ),
    marker=dict(
        color='#EB89B5'
    ),
    opacity=0.75
)
data = [trace1, trace2]

layout = go.Layout(
    title='Sampled Results',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Value'
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Count'
    ),
    bargap=0.2,
    bargroupgap=0.1
)

steps = []
for i in range(len(trace1)):
    step = dict(
        method = 'restyle',
        args = ['visible', [False] * len(trace1)],
    )
    step['args'][1][i] = True # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active = 20,
    currentvalue = {"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad = {"t": 3},
    steps = steps
)]

layout = dict(sliders=sliders)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='Histogram Slider')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You could create a list of histograms, let's say 3 days (`total_days = 3`, odd numbers are experimental, even numbers are control).
- Only the first traces are shown (`visible = day < 1`).
- Each step in the slider shows/hides another pair of traces.

[image]

```
import plotly
import numpy as np
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

total_days = 3

data = list()

for day in range(total_days):
    data.append(plotly.graph_objs.Histogram(
        x=np.random.randn(500) + day * 0.5,
        histnorm='count',
        name='Day {}, control'.format(day),
        visible=day < 1
      )
    )
    data.append(plotly.graph_objs.Histogram(
        x=np.random.randn(500) + day,
        histnorm='count',
        name='Day {}, experimental'.format(day),
        visible=day < 1
      )
    )

steps = list()
for i in range(total_days):
    step = dict(
        method='restyle',
        args=['visible', [False] * total_days * 2],
        label='Day {}'.format(i)
    )
    step['args'][1][i * 2] = True
    step['args'][1][i * 2 + 1] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    steps=steps
)]

layout = dict(sliders=sliders)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my issue! Another questionif I may: assuming the x Axis were not represented by numerals, but by classes, whose count changes each day, how would that factor in the code you provided? What I mean is, think you have three names ('Max', 'Ivo', 'Nina'), and for each day we plot their weight, stored beforehand in an array for each day. 'Max' would thus have an array of 3 values [80 81 85], same for the other two.

Comment: Not sure if I understood it correctly, but wouldn't that be a simple bar plot with 3 categorical x-values? But I suggest, just post another question, comments are hide to find and it might help other users as well.

Comment: Yes, basically also a bar plot with a slider. But no need for another question now, thanks to your example above I was able to easily change the code myself. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you both so much. This is a good example, which makes the behaviour of slider very clear. The example in the official documentation is just incredibly messy, and this should be used instead:

https://plot.ly/python/sliders/